# How Do You Insert XML Into an existing XML node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm not even sure if it's possible but say I have some XML:

```
   <source>
        <list>
            <element id="1"/>
        </list>
    </source>
```

And I would like to insert into list:

```
<element id="2"/>
```

Can I write an XSLT to do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add these 2 template definitions to an XSLT file:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="list">
  <list>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *"/>
     <element id="2"/>
  </list>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  We have vendor config files where we have to add a bunch of custom properties.  Ideally we would like to automate this rather than hand edit it everytime.

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome answer even 7 years later. :)